# Is it acceptable/usual to write multiple conditional probability pipes simultaneously? eg, $\tilde P(L \mid M_2)\equiv P(L \mid M_2\mid M_1)$

Tags: probability, notation

***I'm NOT asking for the solution to this exercise that's publicly accessible.*** Rather, please see the green and red underlines (from Blitzstein, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn), Ch 2, Exercise 26, p 87. p 12 in the publicly downloadable PDF of curbed solutions).

[image]

If I apply the author's green definition to the red underline, then $$\tilde P({\color{red}{L \mid M_2}}) \equiv P(\color{red}{L \mid M_2} \quad \color{limegreen}{\mid M_1})$$

Is it natural or wont to write multiple Conditional Probability [pipes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/110194) simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation with two vertical lines is wrong, and it comes down to what precisely the vertical line means in conditional probability.

$P(A\mid B)$ is "the probability of $A$, assuming $B$ is known to be true", not the probability of some event $A\mid B$. In that sense, $P(A\mid B)$ and $P(A)$ are quite different functions, despite having the same name $P$.

We are given the definition that $\tilde P(A)=P(A\mid M_1)$. This definition doesn't actually tell us what $\tilde P(A\mid B)$ should be, but we can infer that it should be something like "the probability of $A$, assuming $B$ is known to be true, assuming $M_1$ is known to be true."

This, as was written in the linked paper, means that $\tilde P(L\mid M_2)$ equivalent to $P(L\mid M_1\cap M_2)$.